# back button - cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser-history

I have a search-page, and when I get the results (100 results/page) I use a counter/cookie to see how many times the user clicked on another page result. I use this counter for the "back button" to go back to the search page (and remember the inserted search values).

If the user goes to another search-page, it's the same result-page with other results.

Two examples:

1.

> searchpage > result page (counter = 1)
>
> => back button =  window.history.go(-1);

2.

> searchpage > result page (counter = 1) > another result page (counter = 2) > another result page(counter = 3)
>
> => back button =  window.history.go(-3);

This is working fine, but now I have a problem. The user can send the result page to another user by mail, if he clicks on the result page and clicks on the back button, I can't use something like window.history.go(X);

I tried with window.location.href("[url of the searchpage]");, but how can I check in my code if the user came from the search page or from a link in a mail?

I can use document.referrer.indexOf("[url of the searchpage]"). This is ok for the first page, but not if the user goes to another page-result. Because then my document.referrer.indexOf check is always false because he never comes from the search-page.

I work with cookies, if he clicks on the "back"-button I can change the value of the cookie, but if the user just close the page and reopen another result-page, the cookies are still existing and they have a wrong value...

Any idea?

Comment: I guess the only way to do this is too build your search with that in mind (aka URLs that do the job). However, I don't think _any_ users expect the back button to take them back _anywhere_ after opening a link in an email.

Comment: rebuild the search is not possible, I need to adjust an existing program... But I can add cookies on the search-page, but this will not help me I think?

Comment: The text on the back button is "Back to search", so the user will expect to go to the search-page. But this doesn't work at the moment if he opened it in an email

Comment: Back to search will always lead to the same place, no? I mean, you might as well just reset the page when people click this. Even if you want to display the search term, all you have to do is tie it in with JS, read the value of the search, and pre-fill it or something.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are not shared between sessions. When a user opens a website in a new browser (e.g. by clicking a link in an email) that user will start a fresh session with new cookies.

Cookies will be remembered for a period of time in the same browser, even if the user closes the tab/window and returns to it later.

For this reason, it is conventional to use URLs to remember the current pagination in search results, e.g.:

search?q=term&p=4

Then your "Go back" link would have an href value of:

search?q=term&p=3

And for the page before that

search?q=term&p=2

etc.

And to switch to the same page but for a different search term:

search?q=new-search-term&p=2

This works universally and has become a design convention. Don't reinvent the wheel! You should modify the existing program to adopt this methodology, in my opinion.

Comment: I don't need to go back to for example "search?q=term&p=3", I always need to go back to the search page...